# Append (not Insert/Replace) text

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to add some content to the editor programmatically. The executeEdits replaces the text at the given ranges. How can I add/append the text and not replace the existing text? Maybe using the Snippet Commands could be the solution? But somehow I can't find an example how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I could solve this by myself and thanks to other comments on github. Here is the solution on how to append text at specific position:

```
var position = editor.getPosition(); // Get current mouse position

var text = editor.getValue(position);

var splitedText=text.split("\n"); 

var lineContent = splitedText[position.lineNumber-1]; // Get selected line content

var textToInsert = "<div>"; // text to be inserted

splitedText[position.lineNumber-1] = [lineContent.slice(0, position.column-1), textToInsert , lineContent.slice(position.column-1)].join(''); // Append the text exactly at the selected position (position.column -1)

editor.setValue(splitedText.join("\n")); // Save the value back to the Editor

editor.setPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more natural solution can be the to use the [executeEdits](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ICodeEditor.html#executeEdits) method that comes with monaco:

```js
const startLineNumber = 15 // Line number in which the content will start being typed
const startColumn = 5 // Column number in which the content will start being typed
const endLineNumber = 18 // Line number in which the text will finish
const endColumn = 25 
const text = "This is the new text" // The content going to be added


const range = new monaco.edito.Range(startLineNumber, startColumn, endLineNumber, endColumn); // It will go to the specific position of the editor

const id = { major: 1, minor: 1 }; // Required generic id

const editOperation = {identifier: id, range: range, text: text, forceMoveMarkers: true}; // The operation going to be performed

monaco.editor.executeEdits("custom-code", [ editOperation ]); // Runs the instruction
```

The good part of the code above is that it can add, delete, update and replace existing code, so it will be very efficient and the end user will see it like if he/she was typing.